# Why is AutoPostBack trying to load a page if I only have it for set for a DropDownList in an update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DropDownList in a popup where I am trying to get a user's input. I also have a "onselectedIndexChanged" for getting the users input. I have my entire DropDownList in an updatePanel so that only the DropDownList gets updated.(the popup is built using JQuery/JS) I user JS to the hiddenfield value then pass it to another function)
Here is my code :

```
<div id="ddlFiles">
    <label>
        Select new CaseFile:</label>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesNew" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
                DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCaseFilesNew_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCaseFilesNew" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

and here is my selectedIndexChanged:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void ddlCaseFilesNew_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidNewCaseFile.Value = ddlCaseFilesNew.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
</script>
```

Now for some reason as soon as I select something from the list it sends me to a "cannot find resource " page. I don't know why it does that. My url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:49355/base/Expenses/ViewExpenses.aspx?CaseFileID=2001
```

When I try to select a value, it opens that error (cannot find resource) page and says I can't find the link.

Here is a picture of the error:[image]

Page_load:

```
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    if (!isLoggedIn())
        return;

    if (Request.QueryString["ExpenseID"] != null)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCaseFilesNew.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
            ddlCaseFilesNew.SelectedIndex = -1;
            ddlCaseFilesNew.DataTextField = "Display";
            ddlCaseFilesNew.DataValueField = "FileID";
            ddlCaseFilesNew.DataBind();
            if (Request.QueryString["CaseFileID"] != null)  // from view>casefiles>casefile#>notes
                hidCaseFile.Value = Request.QueryString["CaseFileID"].ToString();
        }
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["CaseFileID"] != null)  // from view>casefiles>casefile#>notes
        hidCaseFile.Value = Request.QueryString["CaseFileID"].ToString();
    else if (Request.QueryString["FileID"] != null && Request.QueryString["TaskID"] != null)    // from view>task>specific task notes
    {
        hidCaseFile.Value = Request.QueryString["FileID"].ToString();
        hidTaskID.Value = Request.QueryString["TaskID"].ToString();
    }
}

protected void ddl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    try
    {
        if (ddl.Items[0].Value != "-1")
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }
    catch
    {
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
    }

}
```

Comment: What other code do you have in your code behind?  An `UpdatePanel` may just be "updating" a small section of your page, but it does load the entire page in the background, thus running through any event handlers for the page you have in your code behind.

Comment: I'll put the info in the main question so you have a better format to look at

Comment: You posted a slightly different version of this in another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679720/how-do-i-get-dropdownlist-selected-value-from-user-in-asp-netselectedindexchang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting UpdateMode="Conditional" for your UpdatePanel and then try agaian..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```