# How do I get DropDownList selected value from user in Asp.Net(selectedIndexChange)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do I go about getting the selected value from the DropDownList in asp.Net using selectedIndexChanged with an update Panel? I've tried but when I add the AutoPostBack to my DropDownList, it sends me to an error page saying it cannot find the resource.(doesn't even hit my "selected_IndexChanged") I have the hiddenField being assigned the selected value.

Here is my DropDownList:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesNew" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
                DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCaseFilesNew_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="False">
                <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCaseFilesNew" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click on a value inside the DropDownList it sends me to a "cannot find resource" page. I have no idea why. It doesn't even touch my "onSelectedIndexChanged"

```
  <script runat="server">
    protected void ddlCaseFilesNew_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidNewCaseFile.Value = ddlCaseFilesNew.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hiddenField.Value = dropdownlist.SelectedItem.ToString() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SelectedIndex function, use

```
string sValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
```

Since it's in an update panel, you likely won't have access to it via the designer (this.DdlId).

Based on your comment in the OP, this is likely what you need:

```
protected void ddlCaseFilesNew_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidNewCaseFile.Value = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
}
```

You also need to move your hidden field into the ContentTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
protected void myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var res = this.myDropDownList.SelectedValue;
}
```

Or:

```
protected void myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    var res = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

#### Edit 1

You need to understand that the partial page rendering occurs for all **controls inside an `UpdatePanel`**, in your case, you are trying to set the `Value` property of `hidNewCaseFile` control which does not appear to be **inside the `UpdatePanel`** therefore, its value will never get updated

Comment: Beat me to it, but the top example is unlikely to work for OP because it's in an updatepanel.

Comment: It doesn't matter, an `UpdatePanel` control is used to send **partial** Async postbacks back and forth the server. Your **server code will work as usual, that's the purpose of the UpdatePanel**

Comment: If it's in an UpdatePanel its not a control of the page, its a control that belongs to the UpdatePanel.

Comment: And? That's not even related to the problem. That would be relevant if we were talking about data bound controls. I invite you politely to try it out, you **can access the controls inside an `UpdatePanel`, `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`** by their **page's ID's**

Comment: I didn't know that. I haven't used AJAX.NET in at least 5 years, but thank you for that info.